# how to use Intersection Observer API immediately?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to know when the element is in the viewport or not, which works fine.

How to use Intersection Observer API to know if the element is in the viewport **without using callback**?

Something like:

```
 let options = {
   root: ..
   rootMargin: '0px',
   threshold: 1.0
  }

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

  const status = observer.isInViewport(); // <------- this what I looking for or something similar. not callback.
```

Answer (score -1):

its better to be in mounted lifecycle hook because you are using refs, and that means onMounted in composition api. but the is in your callback and here it is:

```
    const ready = ref(false);
    const myRef = ref(null);

   onMounted(() => {
  const vm = getCurrentInstance();
  let options = {
   root: vm.$refs.myRef
   rootMargin: '0px',
   threshold: 1.0
  }

   let observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
      if (entry && entry.isIntersecting) {
        ready.value = true;
      }
    }, options);
     observer.observe(myRef.value)
 })

  return { ready, myRef }
```

Comment: no, ready in the template have set to `false` then to `true`.

Comment: well at first you set it to false. here const ready = ref(false);

Comment: this is not a sync way. sorry, it not answer for my question. please read again my question